# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str при работе с vk api

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

При попытке выполнить скрипт, написанный по мануалу https://proglib.io/p/python-vk-api-1/ ловлю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/PyProject/vkproject/pyvkproj.py", line 25, in <module>
    PHOTOS_COUNT = VKAPI.photos.getAlbums(owner_id=OWNER_ID, album_ids=ALBUM_ID)['items'][0]['size']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Ссылка на код - https://github.com/Shtihl/PyProject/blob/master/vkproject/pyvkproj.py

Складывается ощущение, что изначально код в примере с ошибкой, пытаюсь понять, где.

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str  перевод от google             
Индексы списка должны быть целыми или срезами, а не строками

Comment: >>> s ='abcde'
>>> s[1]
'b'